# How to fill campaign template with repeatablecontent via Mailchimp Marketing API

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have campaing which uses template and I need to send this campaign via Marketing API with 5 (or more) latest job offers. I trying to find the way to do it.

I've tried to use Template Language on simple example.

I've added this block to template: `<h3 mc:edit="article_title">Title</h3>`

And then I try to update campaign content with PHP library `mailchimp/marketing:3.0.27`:

```
$campaign = $this->mailchimp->campaigns->setContent($campaignId, [
    'template' => [
        'id' => (int) $templateId,
        'sections' => [
            'article_title' => 'Test title',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

This request runs successfully, but I don't see any changes in response, campaing design or test email.

What I doing wrong? Or maybe there is another way to solve my problem?

I also tried to ask Mailchimp support about this problem, but got no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is that this feature was not implemented and will not work.

Comment: I used Postman to set the campaign content and it worked successfully. Here's the JSON object I sent:
`{
    "campaign_id": "{{Mailchimp campaign id}}",
    "template": {
        "id": {{Mailchimp template id}},
        "sections": {
            "body_content": "<div>Hello Everyone</div>"
        }
    }
}`
After sending it I saw my changes in the campaign.